# Extracting the best matches from a map in Golang

Tags: go

This is what I have as an input (I've kept it short but it can get bigger).

```json
{
    "E-mail": {
        "Email": 0.8333333333333334,
        "Mail": 0.6666666666666667
    },
    "Email": {
        "Email": 1,
        "Mail": 0.8
    },
    "LinkedIn URL": {
        "LinkedIn URL": 1
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract the highest scoring matches from it to create output below.

```json
{
    "E-mail": {
        "Mail": 0.6666666666666667
    },
    "Email": {
        "Email": 1
    },
    "LinkedIn URL": {
        "LinkedIn URL": 1
    }
}
```

However, what I get with my code is this.

```json
{
    "E-mail": {
        "Email": 0.8333333333333334
    },
    "Email": {
        "Email": 1
    },
    "LinkedIn URL": {
        "LinkedIn URL": 1
    }
}
```

This is wrong because a child header is not allowed to be matched with multiple parent headers. As you can see above `Email` (child header) is being matched with `Email` and `E-mail` (parent headers). The first match with score of `1` always wins (*because 1 represents an exact match*) even if there is duplicate else where for same headers.

**CODE**

[Here is the playground link.](https://go.dev/play/p/a41PmiOv5Td)

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    input := `{
        "E-mail": {
            "Email": 0.8333333333333334,
            "Mail": 0.6666666666666667
        },
        "Email": {
            "Email": 1,
            "Mail": 0.8
        },
        "LinkedIn URL": {
            "LinkedIn URL": 1
        }
    }`

    allMatches := make(map[string]map[string]float64)

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &allMatches); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    bestMatches := make(map[string]map[string]float64)

    for parentHeader, matches := range allMatches {

        var (
            bestMatchedScore  float64
            bestMatchedHeader string
        )

        for childHeader, score := range matches {
            if score == 1 {
                bestMatchedScore = score
                bestMatchedHeader = childHeader
                break
            }

            if bestMatchedScore > score {
                continue
            }

            bestMatchedScore = score
            bestMatchedHeader = childHeader
        }

        bestMatches[parentHeader] = map[string]float64{
            bestMatchedHeader: bestMatchedScore,
        }
    }

    res, err := json.MarshalIndent(bestMatches, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}
```

Comment: Include your code in the question

Comment: Based on that input, the output is correct. In the first element, `Email` has the highest score. Why were you expecting that output?

Comment: `E-mail.Email:0.8` (parent:child) match is illegal because child `Email` is already taken by `Email.Email:1` (it is an exact match). Hence it should have been `E-mail.Mail:0.6` where `Mail` is the next match in line. Note: Let's say `Email.Email:1` hasn't taken child `Email` yet - output should still updated to satisfy this expectation.

Comment: I don't see any code which states "this child header is already matched in this parent header" though. Your code only looks at scores.

Comment: @Gimby That's why I am here to turn expectations into code with a help.

Comment: Do I get it right that you need to keep only those child props that have the highest score? What if there will be a parent prop that hasn't any highest score props? Should we skip it totally?

Comment: There will always be a child element within a parent. That's a `1-n` relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't get any more uglier, repetitive and inefficient than this but it solves the problem. Obviously the next step is to improve it. [Code](https://go.dev/play/p/qhGzsb1jUgr).

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    input := `{
        "E-mail": {
            "Email": 0.8333333333333334,
            "Mail": 0.6666666666666667
        },
        "Email": {
            "Email": 1,
            "Mail": 0.8
        },
        "LinkedIn URL": {
            "LinkedIn URL": 1
        },
        "Name": {
            "Fullname": 0.5,
            "Surname": 0.5714285714285714
        }
    }`

    allMatchesWithScores := make(map[string]map[string]float64)

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &allMatchesWithScores); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    allMatchedFileHeaders := make(map[string]struct{})

    for _, match := range allMatchesWithScores {
        for k, _ := range match {
            allMatchedFileHeaders[k] = struct{}{}
        }
    }

    exactMatches := make(map[string]struct{})
    bestMatches := make(map[string]map[string]float64)

    for fileHeader := range allMatchedFileHeaders {

        var (
            bestMatchedParentHeader string
            bestMatchedScore        float64
        )

        for parentHeader, matches := range allMatchesWithScores {
            if _, ok := exactMatches[parentHeader]; ok {
                continue
            }

            for matchedFileHeader, score := range matches {
                if fileHeader != matchedFileHeader {
                    continue
                }

                if score == 1 {
                    bestMatchedParentHeader = parentHeader
                    bestMatchedScore = score

                    exactMatches[parentHeader] = struct{}{}
                    delete(allMatchedFileHeaders, matchedFileHeader)

                    break
                }
            }

            if _, ok := exactMatches[parentHeader]; ok {
                continue
            }
        }

        if bestMatchedParentHeader != "" && bestMatchedScore != 0 {
            bestMatches[bestMatchedParentHeader] = map[string]float64{
                fileHeader: bestMatchedScore,
            }
        }
    }

    for fileHeader := range allMatchedFileHeaders {

        var (
            bestMatchedParentHeader string
            bestMatchedScore        float64
        )

        for parentHeader, matches := range allMatchesWithScores {
            if _, ok := exactMatches[parentHeader]; ok {
                continue
            }

            for matchedFileHeader, score := range matches {
                if fileHeader != matchedFileHeader {
                    continue
                }

                if score > bestMatchedScore {
                    bestMatchedParentHeader = parentHeader
                    bestMatchedScore = score
                }
            }
        }

        if bestMatchedParentHeader != "" && bestMatchedScore != 0 {
            oldBestMatche, ok := bestMatches[bestMatchedParentHeader]
            if !ok {
                bestMatches[bestMatchedParentHeader] = map[string]float64{
                    fileHeader: bestMatchedScore,
                }
                continue
            }

            for name, score := range oldBestMatche {
                if bestMatchedScore > score {
                    bestMatches[bestMatchedParentHeader] = map[string]float64{
                        fileHeader: bestMatchedScore,
                    }

                    delete(bestMatches[bestMatchedParentHeader], name)
                }

                break
            }

        }
    }

    res, err := json.MarshalIndent(bestMatches, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERROR:", err.Error())

        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res) + "\n")
}
```

```json
{
    "E-mail": {
        "Mail": 0.6666666666666667
    },
    "Email": {
        "Email": 1
    },
    "LinkedIn URL": {
        "LinkedIn URL": 1
    },
    "Name": {
        "Surname": 0.5714285714285714
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood your problems, of which there are two:

1. you have nothing in your implementation to prevent a given "child" header being selected as the "best" given a presence in multiple parent items.

That is easily fixed by keeping track of which child items have been matched and excluding them from subsequent matches.  I made a playground for you [demonstrating a solution for that](https://go.dev/play/p/ZUyhW3RHxfM).

However, that still leaves a second problem:

2. fixing the multiple-match issue will not definitively give the output you desire because which child is matched *first* depends on the order of items in the map.

If the "Mail" child is matched first, then an equally valid result is:

```
E-mail      : Email        : 0.8333333333
EMail       : Mail         : 0.8
LinkedIn URL: LinkedIn URL : 1
```

This is the result given by the playground linked above and satisfies the criteria that you subsequently identified (in the comments).

For your desired output to be the *only* valid result, there must be an additional requirement in your assignment:

> matches must be made in order of *absolute* **best match**, *regardless of the ordering of the items in the maps*

It may not be stated precisely this way in your assignment, but that is the gist as far as I can tell.  To achieve that will require you to:

- collate all possible child items
- order them by their score

and only then identify the parents based on *that* order, rather than the canonical order as declared in the maps.

Which I think is best left as an exercise for you.